# Output "Hollywood-hacker-scene" from a shell

Tags: shell

This might seem like a strange question, but what would you use for creating the typical hollywood hacking scene?

I got this request from a friend and my brain was blank. All I could think of was all the nmap scenes from movies like *The Matrix* and so on.

But this would need to be done on a Mac with default OSX, which I think is some flavour of *nix, right? They have no internet access so preparing with external tools is out of the question.

I was thinking along the lines of writing the equivalent of /var/log/messages to screen maybe...

Comment: Take any package, and do a `./configure && make`

Comment: I think Alex is right. Test some different packages as you probably don't want something that compiles for several minutes

Comment: Have a HUGE banner saying "DECODING" and then twelve slot-machine style reels below it with various characters spinning round and stopping one at a time, leaving you with a lowercase dictionary word.

Comment: Install (if possible) FSN or FSV.  "It's a Unix system.  I know this!"

Comment: If nobody ever suggested, you can try running `cmatrix` in a terminal window.

Answer (score 35):

If you're asking how to print one character to the screen at a time (a commonly shown 'hacker' style in Hollywood movies), the following script should suffice (it takes input from `stdin`).

In `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    length="${#line}"
    bol=1
    for (( offset = 0 ; offset < length ; offset++ )); do
        char="${line:offset:1}"
        printf '%s' "$char"
        if (( bol )) && [[ "$char" == " " ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        bol=0
        sleep 0.05
    done

    if (( length == 0 )); then
        sleep 0.$(( RANDOM % 3 + 2 ))
    else
        sleep 0.$(( RANDOM % 7 + 3 ))
    fi

    printf '\n'
done
```

Or, a simpler version in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[1];
    int len;

    while ((len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, len) != len) {
            perror("write");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        usleep(50000);
    }
    if (len != 0) {
        perror("read");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you wanted to use `dmesg` as input, for example:

```
dmesg | hollywood
```

Comment: Definitely a funky script

Comment: Adding some `$RANDOM` delays in the timings might be fun too :-)

Comment: Adding modem line noise would be even better. This may become the most edited post on UL.

Comment: @Stéphane That would have too much overhead to be desirable for each character, but it's a good idea for the EOL. Will implement it in a second.

Comment: @Tim Again, it would have too much overhead to be desirable to have a random chance of line noise for each possible character, but it's not too bad at the EOL... maybe we can even exit with `NO CARRIER` or similar. I'll look into implementing it.

Comment: @Stéphane I implemented a sleep at EOL based on the decimal ASCII character code of the last character on the line.

Comment: @ChrisDown You should exit with `+++`, the common Hayes escape code (well, in order to get to the modem again), at which point .. _nothing else is heard_. zmodem at this point got totally p0wned and all hope is lost, while some 9 year old snags your user list.

Comment: No idea what Tim means by line noise, but I would implement it as changing the first `printf` to `printf '\b%s%c' "${_line:_offset:1}" $RANDOM` and adding `printf '\b \b'` before the second `sleep`.

Comment: HAHAHAH I just ran this with dmesg and freaking laughed! Please keep updating this, it is epic.

Comment: This is halarious. Definitely a winner for "hacky" output...

Answer (score 14):

```
export GREP_COLOR='1;32'; cat /dev/urandom | hexdump -C | grep --color=auto "ca fe"
```

This (and other commands from http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6663/pretend-to-be-busy-in-office-to-enjoy-a-cup-of-coffee) also seems very ,,hackish'' and confuses most people that stare at the terminal at the given moment ;)

Comment: No need to export GREP_COLOR, and you don't need to use cat. Just use `hexdump -C /dev/urandom | GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep --color=auto 'ca fe'`

Comment: +1000 Now that's a great answer!

Answer (score 6):

1. Use Compiz with things like Wall, Expose, partially transparent windows, etc.
2. Use tcpdump on at least one screen.
3. Use IRC and Irssi to talk to other "Hackers" on another screen.
4. Compile a Kernel. you don't need to install it, just compile it, make the modules, then start over by cleaning compiled objects and restarting the compile. use GCC color to enhance the effect.
5. Have OpenBSD boot up on one screen, you can use a VM for this, if you don't have a spare machine.
6. Line-by-line print of `dmesg`.
7. Open a few source code files in Gvim, and use the Cobald colorscheme or [mine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aPolemon/files/polemon.vim).
8. Modify xscreensaver "phosphor" and start it in a window. It can print stuff character by character. I've used it a couple of times for visual effect.
9. Use mplayer with aalib or cacalib. There is a matrix filter, but that might seem like a cheap ripoff.
10. I suggest using zsh, with colored ls output (dircolor), as well as a nice shell.

Answer (score 4):

How about this setup for a Hollywood hackish setup?

- Don't use a windowmanager that looks like windows or mac, all of the others looks hackish since normal guy don't know what it is.
- Select some really nerdy colours for the terminal like "amber on black" or "green on black".
- Have the hexdump from random (like *Wiesław Herr* described) running in a window in the background.
- Have something that looks like a log running in another window, maybe a tcpdump that is almost human readable.
- etc etc

That should be a nice fake start.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do that some month ago. I just fired "find /" and it was enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
pv /var/log/messages -qL 100
```

Running `man pv` gives the following definitions for `q` and `L` flags.

> -q, --quiet - No output.  Useful if the -L option is being used on its own to just limit the transfer rate of a pipe.
>
> -L RATE, --rate-limit RATE - Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE bytes per second.  A suffix of "k", "m", "g", or "t" can be added to denote kilobytes (*1024), megabytes, and so on.

the `100` is the number of **bytes/second**

P.S. great todler protector (Make sure you are not in Window mode <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> works better that way)

**EDIT**

- Source code if you need to make it http://pipeviewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
- Link to google code http://code.google.com/p/pipeviewer/source/checkout

Comment: Why are you using `less` at all? Just redirect the file into `pv`.

Comment: oops an oversite, Usually i use `man rsync` i moded it for the question. Fixing..

Comment: Some googling suggests that `pv` isn't available by default on Mac (available through HomeBrew and Ports though).

Comment: It's not here on on my 10.6 installation...

Comment: Ive got it working on Ubuntu and Fedora, Ive never used macs so im not sure what the requirement for that be, but im sure you can make install it. Im not sure where one could download the package

Comment: added links if you like to try on OSX's

Answer (score 3):

**This might seem like a strange question, but what would you use for creating the typical hollywood hacking scene?**

[Hollywood technodrama](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/12/hollywood-technodrama.html), should be enough inspiration for what you are looking for. It is available as a package for Linux, also on [github](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/hollywood), should be able to pick apart bits you like and package up something on OS X.

On a Debian/Ubuntu system you can install like so:

```
sudo apt-get install hollywood
```

Or if that doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hollywood/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hollywood
```

Answer (score 2):

from commandlinefu:

`tr -c "[:digit:]" " " < /dev/urandom | dd cbs=$COLUMNS conv=unblock | GREP_COLOR="1;32" grep --color "[^ ]"`

or

`echo "You can simulate on-screen typing just like in the movies" | pv -qL 10`

Answer (score 1):

I understand that nmap is the standard hackish hollywood app, and [here's a page](http://jtnimoy.net/workviewer.php?q=178) from a guy who worked to make the Hollywood hacking on Tron more real.